# Question on using this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I tried copying a pointer to another by using a method inside the class and the `this` pointer as follows. I am giving the entire test code so that it is clear what is going on.

```
class test  {
private:
    int x;
public:
    void setx(int x);
    int getx(void);
    void copy(test *temp);
};

void test::setx(int x)  {
    this->x = x;
}

int test::getx(void)    {
    return this->x;
}

void test::copy(test *temp) {
    this = temp;
}
```

And I access this method from the main as follows:

```
int main()  {
    test a;
    a.setx(4);
    cout << a.getx()<<endl;
    test *b = new test;
    b->setx(4);
    cout << b->getx()<<endl;
    test *c;
    c=b;
    cout << c->getx()<<endl;
    test *d;
    d->copy(b);
    cout << d->getx()<<endl;
}
```

However it gives the following error

```
In member function ‘void test::copy(test*)’:
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

All the other method involving the `this` pointer works fine except for the copying part. Am i doing some elementary mistake in using the `this` pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot overwrite `this`. The `this` pointer is a constant, so you're not allowed to change it. And what would that mean anyway? You can't change the object that you're in. You can change the values within that object, but not the object itself.

You need to copy other objects by value (by what is stored in the object), not by pointer.

Also, you shouldn't have a function called `copy`; that's what copy constructors and copy assignment operators are for.

Comment: Ok. But then why is `c=b` fine and working? Even there I am copying a pointer variable into another right?

Comment: `this` is not a pointer _variable_. Because it cannot _vary_. It is a pointer _constant_, as in unchanging. `c` and `b` are variables; `this` is constant.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up. I have anyways accepted your answer.

Comment: Technically, `this` is not a constant, but a scalar prvalue. But it does not hurt too much if think of it as a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the `this` pointer. You can however modify `*this`:

```
void test::copy(test *temp)
{
    *this = *temp;
}
```

Also, you should rename the data member or the parameter, so you don't need `this->`:

```
class test
{
int m_x;
public:
void setx(int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

what is test::copy supposed to do?
Clearly you cant assign a different address to your current object. So it is invalid.

if this is supposed to initialize the current object with the values of some other object then it should look like this:

```
void test::copy(test *temp) {
    this->x = temp->getX();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up. It was helpful.